# Loading smaller boxes into a bigger one in Java3D

Tags: java, java-3d

So I am having trouble putting smaller boxes into a bigger one(container). I tried to get the coordinates of a vertex from a box and put the other in that position. Here is the code I tried:

```
 Shape3D backShape = ((Box) buildShape(x, y, z)).getShape(Box.RIGHT);

    GeometryArray geo=(GeometryArray)backShape.getGeometry();
    float[] position=new float[3];
    geo.getCoordinate(0, position);
    System.out.println(position[0]+" "+position[1]+" "+position[2]);
    Vector3f pp = new Vector3f (position[0],position[1], position[2]);

    Color3f c1=new Color3f(0.7f, .15f, .15f);
    Color3f c2=new Color3f(0.7f, .15f, .15f);
    Color3f[] c=(Color3f[]) new Color3f[20] ; 

        c[0] =new Color3f(Color.getHSBColor(20.f, 30f, 2.f));
        c[1] =new Color3f(Color.BLUE);
        c[2] =new Color3f(Color.YELLOW);
        c[3] =new Color3f(Color.GREEN);
        c[4] =new Color3f(Color.WHITE);
        c[5] =new Color3f(Color.CYAN);
        c[6] =new Color3f(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
        c[7] =new Color3f(Color.PINK);
        c[8] =new Color3f(Color.RED);
        c[9] =new Color3f(Color.DARK_GRAY);
        c[10] =new Color3f(Color.MAGENTA);
        c[11] =new Color3f(Color.getHSBColor(0.2f, 0.15f, 2.f));
        c[11] =new Color3f(Color.getHSBColor(0.8f, 0.1f, 15.f));
        c[13] =new Color3f(Color.ORANGE);
        c[11] =new Color3f(Color.getHSBColor(1.f, 0.8f, 2.f));

    for (int i=0; i<boxes.size(); i++) {

            Transform3D transform = new Transform3D();
            transform.setTranslation(pp);
            Box ProductBox = addProductBox(boxes.get(i).dimension.get("length"),boxes.get(i).dimension.get("breadth")
                    ,boxes.get(i).dimension.get("height"),c1, c2,c[i],c[i]);

            Transform3D rotateCube = new Transform3D();
            rotateCube.set(new AxisAngle4d(1.0, 1.0, 0.0, Math.PI / 4.0));
            TransformGroup rotationGroup = new TransformGroup(rotateCube);
            TransformGroup TranslateGroup = new TransformGroup(transform);
            TranslateGroup.setCapability(TransformGroup.ALLOW_TRANSFORM_WRITE);
            rotationGroup.addChild(ProductBox);
            TranslateGroup.addChild(rotationGroup);
            nodeRoot.addChild(TranslateGroup);
            Shape3D shape = ProductBox.getShape(Box.FRONT);
          GeometryArray g=(GeometryArray)shape.getGeometry();
            position[0]-= boxes.get(i).dimension.get("length")+0.15f;
           System.out.println(position[0]+" "+position[1]+" "+position[2]);

           Vector3f pp2 = new Vector3f (position[0],position[1],position[2]);
           pp=pp2;
           c[i]=c[i+1];
    }
```

I succeeded in positioning all the boxes in the container by substracting the length from position[0] in each iteration. But the boxes are not lined up.
I attached an image showing what I have done so far:
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0iQwC.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have this simple program. Say you have a Shape3D shape:

```
GeometryArray ge=(GeometryArray)shape.getGeometry();
double[] cc1=new double[3];
ge.getCoordinate(0, cc1);
System.out.println(cc1[0]+" "+cc1[1]+" "+cc1[2]);
ge.getCoordinate(1, cc1);
System.out.println(cc1[0]+" "+cc1[1]+" "+cc1[2]);
```

This way I can get the coordinates of shape. You have to be well positioned into 3D space to understand. You have to experiment by positioning your object (one only at first).

Comment: Thanks alot! 
So, it worked for the first box but when I tried to position a second one next to the first it didn't.

Comment: I edited my question , I tried to use the length of the box i put each time . It worked but the boxes are not on the same line.

Comment: I attached a new image too

Comment: maybe it has to do with the rotations etc (remove the transforms for now and try) - just open a new question as this exceeds the current one -  you may want to add the old code back for reference purposes